# How to make text break to new line with breaking layout in flex box?

Tags: css, flexbox, styled-components

I have a flex box containing text but, when The text content becomes more, the text loses it's layout.

I am using styled components and my code is like below:

```
<styled.SpecsData key={index}>
    <Text fontSize="16px" lineHeight="32px" fontFamily="PT Sans Bold" color="colorPrimary">
        {spec?.name}
    </Text>
    <styled.SpecDataValues> 
       <Text fontSize="16px" lineHeight="32px" color="colorPrimary">
          {spec?.value}
          {spec?.units}
       </Text>
    </styled.SpecDataValues>
</styled.SpecsData>

export const SpecsData = styled.div`
    max-width: 100%;
    height: max-content;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.gray};
`

export const SpecDataValues = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
`

const Text = css`
    color: ${ props => ({ theme }) => theme.colors[props.color] || theme.colors.grayDark };
    font-size: ${ props => props.fontSize || "14px"};
    font-family: ${ props => props.fontFamily || "PT Sans"};
    line-height: ${ props => props.lineHeight || "32px"};
    letter-spacing: ${ props => props.letterSpacing || "0.019rem" };
    margin: ${ props => props.margin || "0" };
    ${media.desktop`
        font-size: ${ props => props.fontSizeDesktop };
        line-height: ${ props => props.lineHeightDesktop };
    `}
`
```

```css
.spec-data {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: max-content;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #757575;
  color: white;
}

.spec-data-values {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="spec-data">
  <p>
   this is a test
  </p>
  <div class="spec-data-values">
    <p>
    testing 1 2 3
    </p>
    <p>
     testing 4 5 6 7 8 testing 9 10 11 12 14 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
     22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I adjust this code to make it not break when the text content becomes more. I want the text to break to new line without breaking the layout

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex: 1`

```
.spec-data-values {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```css
.spec-data {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: max-content;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #757575;
  color: white;
}

.spec-data-values {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="spec-data">
  <p>
    this is a test
  </p>
  <div class="spec-data-values">
    <p>
      testing 1 2 3
    </p>
    <p>
      testing 4 5 6 7 8 testing 9 10 11 12 14 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```